# Calculate each element in a matrix based on elements in two other matrices

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I'm trying to populate a matrix with i x j entries from a random normal distribution based on the means and standard deviations stored in two other matrices. Is there a way to use rnorm pulling each entry from the two "data" matrices (the two matrices with the means and standard deviations) without using a loop?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: You could also just draw standard random normals, multiply by your standard deviations and add your means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just do it:

```
means <- matrix(1:4, 2, 2)
sds <- matrix((1:4)/1000, 2, 2)
result <- matrix(rnorm(4, mean = means, sd = sds), 2, 2)
```

or (following the comment from Frank below)

```
result <- array(rnorm(length(means), mean = means, sd = sds),
                dim = dim(means))
```

Comment: Or to avoid writing the dims manually, `res = array(dim=dim(means)); res[] = rnorm(length(means), means, sds)` also extends to arrays of values this way, I guess. Or... `array(rnorm(stuff), dim=dim(means))`